# Strange use of CSS ::before, ::after

Tags: css

Saw this bit of CSS in a [Sitepoint example](http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/imJGz) (from [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/are-we-ready-to-use-flexbox/)), and can't understand what it's supposed to do. Obviously the first selector applies the box-sizing style to everything, but I don't understand the use of `::before`/`::after` in this case. I know those are used to add content before or after a given element, but what purpose does it serve here?

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: I think this can be modified to this: `*, ::before, ::after { box-sizing: border-box;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will force any `::before` or `::after` element to use the `box-sizing` property as well, as you can shape them as if they are boxes. The `*` does not include these pseudo-elements, so `*::pseudo` will do that for you.

Comment: You actually read the question! ^_^ "The `*` does not include psuedo-elements" is the critical part here.

Answer (score 2):

thats the old implementation of :

> The double colon replaced the single-colon selectors for
>   pseudo-elements in CSS3 to make an explicit distinction between
>   pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements. For backward compatibility, the
>   single-colon syntax is acceptable for pre-CSS3 selectors. So, :after
>   is a pseudo-class and ::after is a pseudo-element

the : is used for :before and :after pseudo-elements which together with the content: allow you to put something for example an image or icon etc before/after every selector you specified

So, here you are selecting everything and applying box-sizing property and style before and after it, as * does not include psuedo-elements

Answer (score 0):

The selector means:

apply to all elements, apply to contents before each element, and apply to contents after each element.